# Logitech dpi shift using modifier

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I thought this would be relatively easy to do with Logitech lua.
Basically, all I want it to do is when I press left shift it shifts my dpi up. But this doesn't do anything. Am I missing something or does the keyboard have to be a Logitech keyboard for lua to recognise the left shift press?

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if IsModifierPressed("lshift") then
      PlayMacro("DPI Up")
   end
end
```

Obviously, this would be much easier to do if Logitech allowed all the keys on their keyboards to be programmed with a simple update to g hub like every other competitive software out there instead of a few g keys.

**UPDATE**

Assigned rshift and ralt to the desired keys in reWASD.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
   while event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" do
      if IsModifierPressed("rshift") then
         PlayMacro("DPI Up")
      end
      Sleep(10)
      if IsModifierPressed("ralt") then
         PlayMacro("DPI Down")
      end
      Sleep(10)
   end
end
```

Comment: maybe I'm wrong but I wouldn't expect that software to work with anything but G Series hardware. why would they provide this to non-customers?

Comment: Only "few G keys" are able to trigger `OnEvent`.  So, you should bind DPI Shift to any button on Logitech mouse or any G key on Logitech keyboard.

Comment: `like every other competitive software out there` - No competitive software allows you to write a script in Lua or other languages.

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff
all the others such as razer, steelseries and corsair all allow you to remap every key on the keyboard. Unlike Logitech who can't introduce such a basic feature. And the whole point of this is to bind the dpi shift key to 'lshift' which can then be remapped in another software to the keys I want. It's a workaround to Logitech's incompetence.

Comment: @Piglet my thoughts too but I couldn't find anything confirming online whether this was true or not for pressed modifiers such as alt, ctrl, shift. I have a Logitech keyboard coming soon to test this on.

Comment: `Logitech who can't introduce such a basic feature.` - I guess this feature was not implemented to make sure a keylogger is impossible to implement on LGS/GHUB.  Users are exchanging their scripts, so all these scripts must be safe.  If you are allowed to handle all keyboard events, you would be able to write malicious scripts.  It would also be possible to easily make keyboard unworkable in case of mistake in script.  As for now, only G keys functionality could be affected by a wrong script.

Comment: On `razer, steelseries and corsair` you are unable to write malicious script because you can not write scripts there at all.

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff They could let all the keys be remapped without making them accessible with lua like they currently are.

Comment: It would be very strange decision.

Comment: `And the whole point of this is to bind the dpi shift key to 'lshift' which can then be remapped in another software to the keys I want.`  - Could you describe the real problem you are trying to solve?  Why double remapping?  What is the "another software"?

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff I'm trying to have dpi up on keys such as e,f,r,q,c and a few others. Logitech won't allow those keys to be remapped in any way. So this is the only workaround I could think of. With this script in lua I can make Logitech Dpi up when shift is pressed, then in another software called rewasd, remap left shift to all those other keys I want dpi up in while retaining their original output too. And the whole point of this post is to find out how to use the 'IsModifierPressed()' properly.

Comment: OK, I understood.  It is impossible in LGS/GHUB.  But this might be done by writing your own application (you need to compile an EXE file) running in the background: create a mouse+keyboard hook and change mouse move distance to simulate modified DPI while E/F/R/... are down.  Do you have experience in some programming language?

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff unfortunately I don't. I was wondering if it was possible to do something like that but have dpi shift on one of the g keys that can have it and then intercept it and tell the software that when E is pressed, also that g key with dpi shift is pressed too?

Comment: Does your Logitech keyboard have M1 M2 M3 MR keys?  Do you need only the DPI shift functionality?  Or do you have something else in your Lua script?

Comment: @Egor Skriptunofit only has f1-f12 keys to program, its g915 tkl. Yeah, I'm just looking for a button to press that shifts dpi up on keys such as e,f,r,q,c.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need from the script is changing DPI then you may stay inside `OnEvent` forever (you will not be able to handle events).

This script increases DPI while Left Shift is down
(Left Shift can be simulated by another software).

The script works while CapsLock is ON.
Turn CapsLock ON and generate an event (press Right Mouse Button on Logitech mouse or press any remapped G key on Logitech keyboard) to start the script.
Before exiting the game turn CapsLock OFF.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg)
 if event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED" then
   -- some code here
 else
   while IsKeyLockOn("capslock") do
      if IsModifierPressed("lshift") then
         PlayMacro("DPI Up")
         repeat 
            Sleep(30)
         until not IsModifierPressed("lshift")
         PlayMacro("DPI Down")
      end
      Sleep(30)
   end
 end
end
```

---

**UPDATE**

I assume you press MB4 only when Left Shift is not pressed.

```
local prev_btn4

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   repeat
      if IsKeyLockOn("capslock") then
         if IsModifierPressed("lshift") then
            PlayMacro("DPI Up")
            repeat 
               Sleep(30)
            until not IsModifierPressed("lshift")
            PlayMacro("DPI Down")
         end
      end
      Sleep(30)
      local btn4 = IsMouseButtonPressed(4)
      if btn4 and not prev_btn4 then
         MoveMouseTo(46700,55000)
         Sleep(math.random(10, 20))
         PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
      end
      prev_btn4 = btn4
   until not IsKeyLockOn("capslock")
end
```

Comment: Thank you very very much for the help. Also, could I place 'if (event == "PROFILE_ACTIVATED") then' before the  'while IsKeyLockOn' If I have other lines of script in this profile for other mouse buttons? and would that mean I could remove the capslock line?

Comment: `I have other lines of script in this profile for other mouse buttons` - Show the "other lines" of your script.  You can handle `PROFILE_ACTIVATED` event, but not other events.

Comment: This is what I currently have in the game profile https://pastebin.com/b0pfKyyZ. Using the script you provided, would I be able to make it look something like this? https://pastebin.com/362hH5PC. It's got a few too many ends, ignore those.

Comment: ermmm does the g915 tkl even allow lua sctripting? It doesn't recognise the shift or caps lock press or things like 'if (event == "G_PRESSED" and arg == 1) then'. I tried f rather than g and nothing happened.

Comment: `G_PRESSED` works only if the G key is remapped.  Assign a custom macro to it.

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: DUDE, I cannot thank you enough for the help, you have helped me achieve results far better than I expected were possible. In my original post, I will show an update of what I use and the best part about it is that it doesn't require a Logitech keyboard to work which blows my mind.